prometheus last_over_time group by not working
increase(sum (last_over_time(llm_completion_tokens_total{cluster=~"cluster1",namespace=~"ns-1",container="service1",model_name="gpt-40-mini"}[$__range]) or vector(0) )[$__range:]) 

With this I get correct result. But as we have many models , when try to group by model_name it returns zero always.Only displays modelnames
increase(sum by (model_name) (last_over_time(llm_completion_tokens_total{cluster=~"cluster1",namespace=~"ns-1",container="service1",model_name="gpt-40-mini"}[$__range]) or vector(0) )[$__range:]) 

Below is just filter by modelname which gives correct result

Below is groupby by modelname which gives incorrect result , just displays name

